# clearquest api hook and user groups

Tags: hook, clearquest

How can I find out the groups associated with a user that isn't the one logged in currently?
For instance, I want to grab the value of my submitter field and look up the submitter's group list.  I am not logged in as the submitter.

Answer (score 0):

if inGroup(username,"Piper_Admins") then